# `vue-cli-service build` does not generate template's code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand why I'm not seeing anything on screen from my Vue project. I looked at a Vue CLI generated project, and saw this code in `main.js`:

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#appmodified')
```

But I'm using the following code, based on a [sample TODO sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#appmodified',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

This way of instantiating Vue does not return any warnings or errors when I run `npm run build`:

```
> @ build C:\wamp64\www\vuewtest
> vue-cli-service build


\  Building for production...

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1858ms                                                                                        13:14:40

  File                                 Size               Gzipped

  dist\js\chunk-vendors.6018a262.js    65.29 KiB          23.49 KiB
  dist\js\index.377fe308.js            1.96 KiB           1.01 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.

 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

Why does my code show nothing in the browser despite the build completing without error?

`main.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */

//************ this works ************
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#appmodified')

//************ this does not work *************
new Vue({
    el: '#appmodified',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
})
```

`vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    "publicPath": "",
    pages: {
        index:{
            entry: "main.js",
            template: "index.html"
        }
    }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you might not see an error/warning at build time, you should still get a runtime warning in the browser console:

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

By default, Vue CLI projects exclude the runtime compiler, needed to compile string templates or in-DOM HTML at runtime (see [*Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)). If you prefer to use the component's `template` property, configure Vue with the [`runtimeCompiler` flag](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```